# What are the equivalent of setTimeout and setInterval in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Title says it all! I can't find that information anywhere...

- I searched for "schedule" on the main Elixir docs site.
- I DuckDuckGo'd "+elixir periodically send myself a message"
- I DuckDuckGo'd "+elixir scheduling message"

Thanks!

Comment: Dif you look at the Erlang docs : http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4

Comment: I didn't know what to search for in Erlang or Elixir docs, thus I couldn't search for that, @GavinBrelstaff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [`Process.send_after/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.4.2/Process.html#send_after/4), which let me call my own code regularly:

```
defmodule Regular do
  use Xenserver

  def init(state) do
    schedule_call
    state
  end

  def handle_info(:ping, _from, state) do
    schedule_call
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp schedule_call
    Process.send_after(self(), :ping, 1000)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

[**setInterval**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4)

:timer.apply_interval(1000, IO, :puts, ["weeeee"])

[**setTimeout**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_after-4)

:timer.apply_after(...)

[Here is documentation for Erlang's Timer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html)